# Creating an setup.msi packing for asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, installation, web-deployment

I need to create an asp.net setup.msi package using VS2010 and after following the instructions here [Create ASP.NET deployment package using Web Deployment and Web Setup project (MSI installer)](http://codeissue.com/articles/a04df930da62eb1/create-asp-net-deployment-package-using-web-deployment-and-web-setup-project)  I am still unable to create a .msi file.  I don't get any errors.

The output folder shows:

```
  Running aspnet_merge.exe.   Successfully merged '.\TempBuildDir'.
------ Skipped Build: Project: WebSetup1, Configuration: Release ------ Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 7 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========
```

however, I don't see a .msi file in the output.
How would create an msi deployment package?

Comment: Well, maybe because you skip the build of the project? Go to solution settings -> build tab and make sure the project's build option is checked.

Comment: solution settings? where is that located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need an installer, an option would be to use the "Build Deployment Package" that is built in to VS. It creates a zip file which does not contain source code files. All you would need to do is unzip and deploy the files to the appropriate environment. I find it much easier that creating an msi.

Comment: After a weekend of experimenting, The Build Deployment Package was  really painless